# Get Key Pressed in Variable - Visual Studio Basic 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make a simple program, pasting in whatever you write in a textbox. I am doing this in Visual Studio 2017. It is a Windows-Forms App with Visual Basic. It works in the current state, but I woud like to add the ability to customize the key. Right now, when you press F12, it sends the message. I want a simple way of asking the user for a key, and after he presses it, it gets set as the new paste key. Any idea how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

My code below, where I have Keys.F12 I have/want a variable that holds the key set by the user.

```
Dim hotkey As Boolean
hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F12)
If hotkey = True Then
SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
End If
```

Comment: why not using a popup window?

Comment: You should be handling the `KeyDown` event. The key is then contained in the `e.KeyCode` property. Ideally, you would require a key combination, in which case you'd use the `e.KeyData` property.

Comment: *"it gets set as the new paste key"* - I didn't get this logic.

Comment: yeah but how @yoss? @LinuX Man I paste Stuff in by pressing a button. I do this to have something I need always on demand (like a second CTRL+C and CTRL+V) and I want to change the button, maybe with a popup, so I can paste something in with whatever button I want (and I can change it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
Private myNewKey As Char

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(myNewKey) Then
        e.Handled = True ' to prevent getting the Press Key to be entered  
        TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    myNewKey = e.KeyChar
    Label1.Text = "New paste key set to: " + e.KeyChar.ToString
End Sub
```

This program changes the pasting key each time user changes it by their own wish. Just simply declare a variable which holds the new specified key and when the user will get asked to enter a new press key, the variable should be assigned to it.

Eventually, when the user hits the same key, the `TextBox1` KeyPress event will be triggered and the TextBox's text will be set by `Clipboard.GetText`.

Key set to <kbd>5</kbd> and when user hits that during focus on TextBox1 (second box), the text will get pasted.

[image: Custom Key to paste each time]

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, I was looking for something like this, it works great in my programm!

Answer (score 0):

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F12 Then
SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
End If
```